# pgloader not able to load Spanish Language characters

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, pgloader

pgloader is failing to load Spanish language characters sets in PostgreSQL.  Are there any settings in PostgreSQL and/or pgloader that need to be enabled before trying to transfer the data?

Comment: This needs more information. `pgloader` and `Postgres` versions? The `pgloader` command being run? The error messages? Encoding/locale information for the servers? Add responses to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague demonstrated that setting the encoding to LATIN-1 instead of UTF-8 successfully allowed us to load the Spanish language data.